# Vuex how to commit localStorage string to store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm trying to store a value with localStorage through vuex by a click event.

```
methods: {
  click() {
    let string = 'some string';
    this.$store.commit('set_string', string);
},
```

then in my store:

```
const mutations = {
   set_string(state, data) {
      state.string = localStorage.setItem(data);
   }
}
```

but the committed value, never gets to the store and returns `undefined`...

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: localStorage.setItem returns nothing. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: If you want to set an item in localStorage then you need to store value in a key.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');`